# android service onServiceConnected() only on main thread?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

While reading about ServiceConnection class, I came across this documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html) which says "Like many callbacks from the system, the methods on this class are called from the main thread of your process.”

I'm wondering if I create a new thread and implement ServiceConnection methods in that, the system will never be able to invoke onServiceConnected() on it since it's not the main thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thread you use to declare/initialize the connection is irrelevant.  `onServiceConnected` will be called by the main thread.

Comment: Is there any documentation reference for this?